# Why is the result different if I switch the sequence in setting variables by common?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

To explain better, I wrote a small class `node`, and set `a` and `b`:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.val = x 
        self.next = y

a = node(5,6)
b = None
```

Then I found the result is different between:

```
a, a.next, b = a.next, b, a
print(a,b)  #it returns AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
```

and:

```
a.next, a, b = b, a.next, a
print(a,b)  #it returns 6 <__main__.node object at 0x1021a0400>
```

We all know, when `a, b = b, a+b`, it gives a,b value simultaneously, and the result doesn't change when the code becomes `b, a = a+b, b`.

So, could anybody help me with it? Why does this happen?

Comment: May we see the implementation of your list (especially `next`)? In theory, `next` should be internal and shouldn't be played with from outside the class.

Comment: It's from this website. [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list-ii/description/). And the next function is listed in the code area, but I am not sure if you can see it or not. I'll update a pic of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unpacking isn't simultaneously. It's just that the right hand side is "constructed" before it's "unpacked" into the left hand side. But each side is evaluated left-to-right!

So what happens is roughly like this (it actually doesn't build the tuple but that's just an implementation detail):

```
tmp = (a.next, b, a)
a = tmp[0]
a.next = tmp[1]  # fails because "a" is now an integer
b = tmp[2]
```

In the second case it works because is "re-assigned" after "re-assigning" `a.next`:

```
tmp = (b, a.next, a)
a.next = tmp[0]  # a still has the next attribute
a = tmp[1]
b = tmp[2]
```

Comment: Because it doesn't matter if `a = tmp[0]` and `b=tmp[1]` (when you use `a, b = b, a+b`) or `b = tmp[0]` and `a=tmp[1]` (in case of `b, a = a+b, b`). What matters is that the right hand side is evaluated *completely* before it's unpacked into the left hand side (but each side is evaluated left-to-right). I mean, you could even use `a, a = a+b, a` -> then the resulting `a` would just be the original `a` because that's the "last" unpacked assignment to `a` (contrary to `a, a = a, a+b` where the resulting `a` is equal to `a+b` because that's "unpacked last").

Comment: I see your point. The right-hand side elements calculate first, and then unpackage to left-hand side elements one by one from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Tuple unpacking only happens "simultaneously" **when the LHS elements are independent**. Since you have created a situation where they are *not* independent, minor details in the implementation now matter.

In this case, the detail that matters is that the LHS elements are assigned to from left to right. Since `a` contains an `int` by the time `a.next` is looked at, an exception is thrown.

```
import dis

def f1():
    a, a.next, b = a.next, b, a

def f2():
    a.next, a, b = b, a.next, a

print('f1:')
dis.dis(f1)
print()
print('f2:')
dis.dis(f2)
```

...

```
f1:
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 ROT_THREE
             13 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             17 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             20 STORE_ATTR               0 (next)
             23 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE

f2:
  7           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             12 ROT_THREE
             13 ROT_TWO
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             17 STORE_ATTR               0 (next)
             20 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             23 STORE_FAST               0 (b)
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```